# Moving an app and database to a new server

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I have a client that runs an app on an internal server on a WAMP stack. I don't have access to this server remotely and honestly they are not set up to give me that access. What they did do was download a directory that contains the entire app and DB. Is there a way to take that and install it locally? Whats's involved in getting that going?

Looks like MySQL 5.5.8 and PHP 5.3.5

Comment: A little more information would be useful. 1) Do you have a dev server 2) Is it on a Windows or Unix platform 3) Is your dev server flexible enough to easily switch to specific versions of MYSQL and PHP.

Comment: The obvious answer is restore the database to your database. Put the website into a Virtual Host defined on your Dev Server. And off you go

Comment: The plan was to install wampserver 2.1e on my Win 10 laptop and go from there. Will that work. If that is an option can I replace all of the default files with this that we sent to me?

Comment: So. I thought I had it working but I"m just not sure. I installed WAMP 2.1e which had the corresponding MySQL and PHP versions. I copied the entire directory of files given to me and overwrote the default files installed. The app works fine. All the data is accessible. The only think that doesn't seem to be working right is PHPMyadmin or maybe it is. Root + blank password doesn't work but every other username anda blank password does. I do not see anything other than the test DB and the information_schema when I get in. The client gave be their credentials but those don't work either. Ideas?

Comment: That probably means that they have set a password on the `root` MYSQL account, see answer below on how to recover reset that password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to reset the MYSQL root password

Stop the mysql service

```
wampmanager -> MySQL -> Service -> Stop Service
```

Edit the my.ini file

```
wampmanager -> MySQL -> my.ini
```

Find the [wampmysqld] section in the ini file
   Add this line directly after the section [wampmysqld]

```
skip-grant-tables
```

Restart the mysql service.

```
wampmanager -> MySQL -> Service -> Start/Resume Service
```

Open the MySQL console

```
wampmanager -> MySQL -> MySQL Console
```

Now we are going to reset the password for the root user, of course this could be used to reset any users password.

enter the following 2 commands at the mysql> command prompt, each with a semi colon at the end of a line, and press ENTER after each line to issue the command to mysql.

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE user='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Note that the update should report that it has updated more than one row, that because there are actually 3 user accounts with the userid of 'root' each with a different domain i.e. 127.0.0.1, localhost and ::1

Now enter 'quit' at the mysql command promt to exist mysql.

Stop the mysql service

```
wampmanager -> MySQL -> Service -> Stop Service
```

Edit the my.ini file

```
wampmanager -> MySQL -> my.ini
```

Find the `[wampmysqld]` section in the ini file

Remove the 'skip-grant-tables' parameter we added earlier.

**DO NOT Leave this parameter in the ini file its a HUGH security hole.**

Restart the mysql service.

```
wampmanager -> MySQL -> Service -> Start/Resume Service
```

You should now be able to login with phpmyadmin using the userid 'root' and the new password you have just set for that user.

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I needed. Thanks!